# How to find duplicates in all my DB tables without searching each table one at a time?

Tags: database, postgresql

I am new to DB. I have been tasked to find any duplicates in my Postgres DB for our service management application.

I have connected to the DB using pgAdmin 4. The problem is there are over 2000+ tables and there are no help documentation from the vendor to help understand which data is stored within which table. For example, there are multiple user profiles and customer accounts in our DB, all of which have some kind of duplicates.

Can anyone help with some query scripts that will help me achieve:

1. Finding all duplicates in any of my DB tables.
2. How to determine which of the duplicates is safe to delete (which record is the correct one in the application that I want to keep).
3. How I can easily delete/clean up the duplicates safely.

I have managed to run a select statement to find some duplicates in 1 table.

**Query I found online and used:**

SELECT
user_id,
first_name,
last_name,
COUNT(*) AS "Count"
FROM aaauser
GROUP BY
user_id,
first_name,
last_name
ORDER BY first_name ASC;

Comment: For each table you have to define the definition of a duplicate. That would define the group by for each table. When that is done you could write a script that creates the SQL for each table and execute this. Or you call the vendor and let them handle the issue.

Comment: Steps 2 and 3 are impossible to answer without any knowledge about the system you’re working on

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to contact the vendor. Especially since you dare not disclosing neither the application nor the vendor.